# Find value of _HOST in hive-site.xml

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I have an application with does authenticate with kerberos authentication. Application is working well. But I would like to know the _HOST value when I trigger oozie workflow. Is there any possible way where in I can find the value of _HOST either from JAVA program or from oozie actions in workflow.xml

```
<property> 
     <name>hive.metastore.kerberos.principal</name> 
     <value>hive/_HOST@EXAMPLE.COM</value> 
     <description>The service principal for the metastore thrift server. The
     special string _HOST will be replaced automatically with the correct 
     hostname.</description> 
</property>
```

Comment: You could use the shell command "list_principals <expr>" to get to know your principals name and parse the required host information

Comment: @KSNidhin Thanks for your reply, can you please point to some location where I could find more about it? If it is simple enough, could you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a **High Availability** setup, then you **cannot know in advance** which node the JDBC or Metastore client will connect to. That's the purpose of the "_HOST" placeholder: let the library select the host dynamically, then manage Kerberos accordingly.

So if you don't care about HA and really want to **hard-code** the host name, just update your `hive-site.xml` and replace "_HOST" with a hard-coded FQDN. Problem solved.

Comment: Is there a way to know which _HOST is being used? Either by Oozie or any other means. And yes I have HA..

Comment: Repeating louder: you cannot know **IN ADVANCE** i.e. before the connection is open. If you run a custom Java app, then maybe you can use the Java APIs to retrieve the actual host the connection points to; it shows in the JDBC driver logs as `INFO`, for example. But it would be complicated to send that info to Oozie -- see `</capture-output>` flag -- and the info would not be available to Oozie before the Action terminates. Could be too late for your need.